# Scala/Akka load balancing

Tags: scala, load-balancing, akka

I am using Scala/Akka for a server/worker style program. I am currently using a [`RoundRobinRouter`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/routing/RoundRobinRouter.html) for load balancing between my worker actors. But I wonder if there is any better router? Or is there any "best"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ther is a [`SmallestMailboxRouter`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/routing/SmallestMailboxLike.html). This router adds new messages to the slave with the shortest mailboxqueue. You canfind the documentation [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html). Another way is using a [`LoadBalancer`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/1.3.1/#akka.routing.LoadBalancer). I only found it in the pdf.

Comment: What "pdf" are you referring to? I mean about the loadbalancer.

Comment: You can download the documentation as pdf as well. In this pdf I found it.